Babylon 5 characters are holograms created by an adversary
I'm looking for a particular Babylon 5 episode. In this episode some crew members are holograms that were created to resemble the original humans. I'm not sure whether the holograms know in the beginning that they are holograms or not.
In the end they do know about it. They find out that they have been created by an adversary/enemy and trick their creator into his destruction. The holograms manage to transmit their current location to a hostile species causing the destruction of their creator and of themselves.

probably this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesh_and_Blood_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)

@Himarm this is actually not it, although I admit that my description kind of matches. I'll clarify.

The only other two that maybe fits are http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Body_and_Soul_(episode) and http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowplay_(episode)

@cde not a match, either. Thanks, though!

If not that, then maybe the silver blood episode http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Course:Oblivion(episode) but that has no adversary in it and isn't holograms.. Frankly, your description doesn't ring a bell at all in terms of TNG or Voyager episodes. I don't recall any episode of crew members being duplicated like that.

@cde that's because this is a Babylon 5 episode as I just remembered! ;-) Sorry for the confusion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deconstruction_of_Falling_Stars 2762. What's the right way to clean this up? Edit the question and self-answer? In any case the comments here have caused me to remember. They were helpful.

I think a simple self answer would be appropriate.

This is The Deconstruction of Falling Stars, specifically the part that takes place in the year 2762.

Amid growing tension between the Interstellar Alliance and xenophobic elements on Human-settled planets, an anti-Alliance faction attempts to set up forged holographic records to show the heroes of Babylon 5 to be megalomaniacal war criminals. These holograms are based on historical data and recorded memories of the original crew, with the forged records overriding their personalities.

